# How to render JSON in the browser with ExpressJS

Tags: json, express

Hi I have been racking my brains in trying to find a way to display a JSON file in the browser with Express but nothing seems to work.

I am using this as a reference:[response-res](http://sailsjs.org/documentation/reference/response-res/)

I have a function which replaces a JSON file directory with a new path:

```
app.get('/car/model/:filename', function(req, res){
  var filename = req.params.filename;
  var fileDir = __dirname + '/' + filename;
  res.json(fileDir);
})
```

But it only shows the filepath in the browser.Like so:

`/Users/MyUser/Project/OriginalDirectory/data.json`

The closes thing I managed to do was to download the JSON file (res.download(fileDir);) but I need to see it in the browser. How do I do this?

Comment: that link is for sails, which is different to express. Express documentation is here. http://expressjs.com/. Secondly i presume you mean the contents of a json file?

Comment: Yes, the contents of a file, just as if you were to add the URL to a browser and see the file's contents. I cannot find anything explaining this in the expressjs.com URL you sent.

Comment: you need to look into reading the contents of the file and returning that.

Comment: fileDir is path. He should read it by fs module and then put content to res.send

Comment: The same thing, it only sends me the file path. I don't understand how Express works, if I browse to the file, I get JSON, not a file so I really do not understand why the script does not do the same.

Comment: Wondering would a redirect work? `res.redirect(fileDir);`

Comment: Now I just get a CANNOT GET error... :-(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code:

```
//put this in top of file
var fs = require("fs");

app.get('/car/model/:filename', function(req, res){
  var filename = req.params.filename;
  var fileDir = __dirname + '/' + filename;
  var file = fs.readFileSync(fileDir);
  var jsonObject = JSON.parse(file);
  res.json(jsonObject);
})
```

Edit: if json file is very big,then there may be problems with read. Also remember to validate 'filename'. If this is public someone can get access to addictional files

Comment: Hello again, I just saw your comment above. This has done the trick. I would have never guessed! Many thanks. It will not be public for now, but are you saying that including fs enables anyone to read the files?

Comment: when someone write in url yourdomain.com/car/model/otherfile.json then he will get otherfile.json. If you have there only *.json files then ok, but you have there also js file (someone can try get your app.js script - it will crash because js cant JSON parse). Addictionally I think that when someone browse url yourdomain.com/car/model/../../otherfile and guess file in that directory he will get it. Write some clever regexp to check if user want only json file from this directory. Check also if there is any file if no then return 404 code.

Comment: to check if file exist fs.statSync(path).isFile()

Comment: I may have to hold off on this one for a bit as I need to understand better. Working on plugging my file to angularjs now :-)

Comment: maybe check this framework http://loopback.io/ ? It is much simpler because many things it done for you. And it has anguler generator too.

Comment: Hey thanks. I will take a look once I get my head around the whole thing.